# Partial string matching in R and trim the characters

Tags: r, string-matching, fuzzy-search, agrep, fuzzyjoin

Here is a dataframe and a vector.

```
df1  <-  tibble(var1 = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnopqr", "qrst"))
vec <-  c("ab", "mnop", "ijk")
```

Now, for all the values in var1 that matches closest (I would like to match the first n characters) with the values in vec, keep only **upto** first 3 characters of vec in var1 such that the desired solution is:

```
df2 <- tibble(var1 = c("ab", "efgh", "ijk", "mno", "qrst"))
```

Since, "abcd" matches closest with "ab" in vec, we keep only upto 3 characters of "ab" i.e. 2 in this case, in df2, but "efgh" doesn't exist in vec, so we keep it as is i.e "efgh" in df2 and so on.

Can I use dplyr, stringr, fuzzyjoin, agrep, or fuzzywuzzyr to accomplish this? You may want to build upon the following suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51053674/6762788, thanks to Psidom.

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(var1 = ifelse(var1 %in% vec, substr(var1, 1, 3), var1))
```

Comment: what if the value 'tmnop' was in var1, would it return 'mno' or nothing? What if 'nope' is in var1, would it return `nop` or nothing?

Comment: I would like to match the first n characters. So tmnop and nope should return tmnop and nope just like efgh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- tibble(var1 = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnopqr", "qrst","mnopr"))

a = which(adist(vec,df1$var1,partial = T,ignore.case = T)==0,T)

df1%>%
  mutate(var1=replace(var1,a[,2],substr(vec[a[,1]],1,3)))
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  var1 
  <chr>
1 ab   
2 efgh 
3 ijk  
4 mno  
5 qrst 
6 mno
```

Comment: That's really interesting! Can you also make it case insensitive and a different variable, say var2? So, AB should match with ab and so on.

Comment: @Geet within the function `adist(...,ignore.case=TRUE)` include `ignore.case=TRUE` or even in the `grep` function, you can include `ignore.case=TRUE` this will make it case insensitive

Comment: This solution works for the given example but breaks down when there are more matches in df1, e.g. `df1  <-  tibble(var1 = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnopqr", "qrst","mnopr"))` - in this case the output leaves `mnopqr` unchanged

Comment: @Onyambu: I won't be able to reproduce my real data, but the above method gave me this error: Column var1 must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 1166955. Any idea what might be the problem and how to fix that?

Comment: @Geet Your data is grouped. You need to ungroup it. ie `df1%>%ungroup()%>%mutate(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a two step solution.  First, a function that does the fuzzy matching and replacing with the first n characters. It runs `agrepl` to match the input pattern to the supplied vector and keeps up to the first `n` characters if they match. If there's no match, it returns `NA`. This is designed to be applied to the vector of patterns via `lapply` so the second function is meant for `Reduce` to turn it into one vector.  `reducer` takes in two vectors of the same length and replaces all instances of the first where the second isn't `NA` with the non-missing value of the second.

This all gets wrapped up in a couple of of calls and returns the vector as desired.

```
fuzzy_match_and_replace = function(pattern, vector, n = 3){
  n = min(c(n,nchar(pattern)))
  match = agrepl(pattern,vector)
  pattern_first_n = substr(pattern,1,n)
  vector_first_n = substr(vector,1,n)
  output = rep(NA,length(vector))
  output[match & pattern_first_n == vector_first_n] = pattern_first_n
  return(output)
}

reducer = function(a,b){
  a[!is.na(b)] = b[!is.na(b)]
  return(a)
}


df1  <-  data.frame(var1 = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnopqr", "qrst"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
vec <-  c("ab", "mnop", "ijk")
Reduce(reducer,lapply(vec,fuzzy_match_and_replace,vector=df1$var1),init=df1$var1)
#> [1] "ab"   "efgh" "ijk"  "mno"  "qrst"
```

If you want it to work in a mutate step, you could have a wrapper like the following

```
wrapper = function(pattern, vector, n = 3){
  Reduce(reducer,lapply(pattern,fuzzy_match_and_replace,vector=vector,n=n),init=vector)
}
```

### UPDATE

Here's a simpler function (1 step) that takes advantage of `adist` from Onyambu's answer but without relying on `max.col`, instead, using `vapply` it walks through the matrix identifying the match and doing a replacement.

```
fuzzy_match_and_replace = function(pattern, vector, n = 3, ...){
  matches = adist(pattern,vector,partial=T,...) == 0
  replace = vapply(apply(matches,2,which)
                  ,function(x){
                    if(length(x) > 0) return(substr(pattern,1,n)[x]) else return(NA_character_)
                   }
                  ,FUN.VALUE = c(""))
  vector[!is.na(replace)] = replace[!is.na(replace)]
  return(vector)
}

library(dplyr)
df1  <-  tibble(var1 = c("abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnopqr", "qrst","mnopr"))
vec <-  c("ab", "mnop", "ijk")

df1%>%
  mutate(var1=fuzzy_match_and_replace(vec,var1))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   var1 
#>   <chr>
#> 1 ab   
#> 2 efgh 
#> 3 ijk  
#> 4 mno  
#> 5 qrst 
#> 6 mno
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and creating such sophisticated functions to tackle this problem!

Comment: Great! Can you also make it case insensitive?

Comment: In the second function you can pass arguments to `adist` via `...` so just add ignore.case=TRUE

Comment: It makes it a lot more flexible.

Comment: I won't be able to reproduce my real data, but the above method gave me this error: Column var1 must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 4. Any idea what might be the problem and how to fix that?